# Display Table From PHP from large number to small number

Tags: php

I want to create 10x10 table from 100 to 1. I can create 1 to 100, but how to create 100 to 1? Here's my code:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
<?php
    for($i=1; $i<=100;$i++)
    {

        echo "<td class='kotak kotak".rand(1,10)."' >$i</td>";
        if($i % 10 == 0)
        {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
?>
</table>
```

I have already tried change the `for loop` to this:

```
$i=100; $i>= 1; $i--
```

but the code for changing row isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this line`if(($i-1) % 10 == 0)`, this will render the table correctly: [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ky4x-in9t)

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <?php
    for($i=100; $i > 0; $i--)
    {

        echo "<td class='kotak kotak".rand(1,10)."' >$i</td>";
        if(($i-1) % 10 == 0)
        {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with -

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <?php
    for($i=1; $i<=100;$i++)
    {

        echo "<td class='kotak kotak".rand(1,10)."' >$i</td>";
        if($i % 10 == 0)
        {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <?php
    for($i=100; $i > 0; $i--)
    {

        echo "<td class='kotak kotak".rand(1,10)."' >$i</td>";
        if($i % 10 == 0)
        {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```